# Javascript and CSS, scaling text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I have a div that acts as a text holder and I want to change the text and "scale the text in" when I click on different links, that will replace the old text with new text in the div.

What is the best way to achieve this? I want the text to start at scale(1.5) and scale down to scale(1.0) over a period of time EACH time a new link is clicked. I have been attempting to set some CSS for the text, but to no avail.

Comment: To clarify, it should look like a slick animation. Text starts big and transitions down to normal size.

Comment: what code have you tried? post it here

Comment: I dont have it available, but it was along the lines of 1.Click a link, that link will call function. Inside function, change the inner html of the div based on the clicked link, set element css to scale(1.5), set transition timer, set scale(1.0), Doesnt work.

Comment: We would need at the bare minimum your HTML, since I can't figure out what your HTML currently looks like. Please update the question as soon as you can.